# IDeviceTopology how to activate interfaces of devicetopology.h?

Tags: c++, windows, com

**Context:** I am trying to activate some of the *Core Audio Interfaces* of "devicetopology.h" such as *IAudioLoudness* and *IAudioPeakMeter* using Component Object Model (COM), I need to get the current volume peak of the system's audio and I believe to have written most of the code necessary to make this work, but I am having trouble when trying to activate these interfaces using IPart::Activate.

**Issue:** When trying to access the *IAudioPeakMeter* Interface after the supposed activation, my console application throws an error 'Debug Assertion Failed!' and the description just says 'Expression: p!=0'. In Visual Studio an exception is thrown stating: 'Access violation reading location 0x00000000', and a deeper look inside the memory tells me that the variable `audio` has a value of `0x00000000 <NULL>`

**Additional Info:** While attempting to fix the issue myself, I rewrote the entire code in a separate environment without the use of the CComPtr (Smart Pointer Class for Interfaces) and it threw me a similar error : 'audio is nullptr'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <devicetopology.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h"
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
  HRESULT hr = S_OK;
  CoInitialize(NULL);

  CComPtr<IMMDeviceEnumerator> enumerator;
  hr = enumerator.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator));
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
  {
    CComPtr<IMMDeviceCollection> devices;
    hr = enumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow::eRender, DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL, &devices);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
    {
        UINT count = 0;
        devices->GetCount(&count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            CComPtr<IMMDevice> device;
            hr = devices->Item(i, &device);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
            {
                CComPtr<IDeviceTopology> topology;
                hr = device->Activate(__uuidof(IDeviceTopology), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&topology);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
                {
                    CComPtr<IConnector> connector;
                    hr = topology->GetConnector(0, &connector);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
                    {
                        CComPtr<IConnector> connectedTo;
                        hr = connector->GetConnectedTo(&connectedTo);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
                        {
                            CComPtr<IPart> part;
                            hr = connectedTo->QueryInterface(&part);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == true)
                            {
                                CComPtr<IAudioPeakMeter> audio;
                                hr = part->Activate(CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IAudioPeakMeter), (void**)&audio);

                                UINT channels;
                                audio->GetChannelCount(&channels); // Causes reading violation
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to programming with COM and haven't been able to figure out how to move forward from this point, I have tried googling the issue and also looking at some examples using other interfaces from DeviceTopology but haven't been able to fix the issue as of yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is unrelated to the actual interfaces you are trying to use. Those are debug assertions from the smartpointer implementations you are using. Read the documentation for those to find out how to use them properly.

Comment: The last Activate probably returns `E_NOINTERFACE` or some other error code and audio is therefore `null`. You want to use `if SUCCEEDED(hr)` like elsewhere in your code

Comment: Yes, hr has the value of `E_NOINTERFACE`